# Consuming MouseClick on TitledPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have this example :

```
public class test extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

        TitledPane pane1 = new TitledPane("TitledPane1",new Button("content1"));

        pane1.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
            e.consume();
        });

        TitledPane pane2 = new TitledPane("TitledPane2",new Button("content2"));

        accordion.getPanes().addAll(pane1,pane2);

        pane.getChildren().add(accordion);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
    }
}
```

I am trying to prevent pane1 from collapsing when clicked on , i would only want it to collapse if pane2 is clicked. Consuming the mouse event as above does not stop it from expanding/collapsing. I am not sure what I'm missing. I am aware of the other work-around for this issue but I am interested in the solution where I consume the mouse event.

Comment: Mousepressed or mousereleased events may be used by `Accordion` for this purpose...

Comment: tried `MousePressed` but still didn't get the expected behavior